# c++ atm save balance reopen program

Tags: c++

I have started on this very simple ATM type of program.
I am a beginner so show some mercy if you see very unefficient ways of doing certain things.

I need help with finding a way of keeping the stored balance value even after I reopen the program. Because right now everytime I reopen the program it does the expected of creating a new "long double balance;" variable which resets its value from the previous use of the program.

So for example, let's say I use the program and deposit 500 euros. Then the balance value would be 500 euros. I close the program, reopen and now everything is reset again. How can I make it so whenever I reopen the program the previous value for balance still exists and does not get reset? As I said there are probably tons of different more efficient ways of doing this but as a beginner this is all I can come up with. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

// Functions
void login();
void menu();
void displayBalance();
void deposit();
void withdraw();
void logout();

// Variables
string name = "";
long double balance;

/* ########################## */

int main(){
    login();
}

void login(){

    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#   Bank/Database  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#  Made by: Fotan  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    // Ask user for name and password
    cout << "Login:" << endl;
    cout << " - Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, name);

    int pw = 0;

    do{
        cout << " - Enter password: ";
        cin >> pw;
    }while(pw != 1234);
    menu();

}

void menu(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#   Bank/Database  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#  Made by: Fotan  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    int choice = 0;

    do{
    cout << "Welcome " << name << "!" << endl;
    cout << " 1 - Display Balance" << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Deposit" << endl;
    cout << " 3 - Withdraw" << endl;
    cout << " 4 - Log out" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    }while(choice > 4 || choice < 1);

    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            displayBalance();
            break;
        case 2:
            deposit();
            break;
        case 3:
            withdraw();
            break;
        case 4:
            logout();
            break;
    }
}

void displayBalance(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#   Bank/Database  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#  Made by: Fotan  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "Balance: EUR" << balance << endl;
    cout << " - Press any key to continue..." << endl;
    getch();
    menu();

}

void deposit(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#   Bank/Database  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#  Made by: Fotan  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    long double amount = 0;

    cout << "Enter amount to deposit: ";
    cin >> amount;

    balance += amount;
    cout << "Amount deposited: " << amount << endl;
    cout << " - Press any key to continue..." << endl;
    getch();
    menu();
}

void withdraw(){

}

void logout(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#   Bank/Database  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "#  Made by: Fotan  #" << endl;
    cout << "\t" "\t" "####################" << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    cout << "Thank you " << name << " for using our services." << endl;
    cout << "You have been logged out!" << endl;
}


/*             __
             <(o )___
              ( ._> /
               `---'    */
```

Comment: Variables are not persistent between program invocations. You will need to make them persist yourself, by saving them to a file, database or whatever.

Comment: Oh alright, that's what I was thinking. I guess i'll try and create some textfile where I store the balance and have it read from it to show the balance and update it and so on. I just thought that there's maybe some other way. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to store them in a file and load them from the file at startup, take a look at fopen/fscanf/fprintf, or the c++ version with fstreams

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not "automagically" persisted when program exits.
So you need to implement a mechanism to persist your `balance` variable (and maybe others) to something on disk.

I would not consider real databases for this pet project, so the most basic thing you can do is write and read the `balance` amount to a file (more specifically a file open in binary mode).

I suggest you to use c++ std::fstream derived, you can find a tutorial [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)